# Check if the image resource is null

Tags: c#, wpf, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I Working on Windows Phone 8 application.

```
string Image = "/MyData/" + myObject.ImageName + "big.png";
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Image , UriKind.Relative));

                MyImage.Source = bmp;
```

I have a image in the folder MyData/, i have 2 sets of images like `<imagename>big.png,<imagename>small.png.`

So here what is happening is i want to check if `<imagename>big.png` exists in the location or not, if not pick `<imagename>small.png.`

How to do it ?

**EDIT**

I solved it myself, here is how.

```
File.Exists("path to file") here path should be `folderName/filenames` and not `/folderName/filenames`
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me.

Comment: Why downvote ? whats wrong in this question ?

Comment: Have you tried File.Exists method?

Comment: @JagathMurali yes i tried it, its not working ,

Comment: What is the reason for down voting ? please give the reason and then down vote it, even after 21+ view i havent got any answers, that doesent mean that you have to down vote it\

Comment: Hope this link will give you some help:- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1eb71a80-c59c-4146-aeb6-fefd69f4b4bb/how-to-detect-if-a-file-exists?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: what is  myObject.ImageName? is this image name? and you are concatenating  with big and small?

Answer (score 0):

```
string image = "/MyData/" + myObject.ImageName + "/big.png";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(image);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
{
 MessageBox.Show("File Exist -"+fileName);
 }
 else
 {
MessageBox.Show("No File Exist -");
}
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image , UriKind.Relative));
if(bmp==null)
 {
 image = "/MyData/" + myObject.ImageName + "/small.png";
bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image , UriKind.Relative));
}
MyImage.Source = bmp;
```

Comment: What are the changes ?

Comment: "/big.png" add a '/' before file name

Comment: Why do i need to add / , my images are in the  folder Mydata/imagename

Comment: could you please explain what is myObject.ImageName in your file path Or could please share your actual file path.

Comment: myObject.ImageName is the file name, i just want to  check if the file is present in the path or not thats it

Comment: I made edit again in my ans, give a look.  And i think problem in only in your file path, you getting always null because your filepath should be /MyData/big.pngbig.png like this